# Estrutura de repetição não funciona quando meu objeto é copiado sem referencia

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso remover um atributo do meu objeto (indexvariacaoatributo), porém preciso que permaneça no objeto raiz.

Esse é meu algoritmo que recebe na variável variacoes meu objeto e depois retiro o atributo indexvariacaoatributo do objeto, dessa maneira funciona perfeitamente o algoritmo, porém além de remover da variavel variacoes, também é removido da variável categoriaForm:

```
    var variacoes = categoriaForm.variacoes
    if(variacoes[0].estoque_variacao == null || variacoes[0].estoque_variacao == 0){
      variacoes = [];
    }
    //Retira do objeto o indexvariacaoatributo
    for(let i=0;i<variacoes.length;i++){
      for (let j=0;j<variacoes[i].atributo.length;j++){
        console.log(variacoes[i].atributo[j].indexvariacaoatributo);
        delete variacoes[i].atributo[j].indexvariacaoatributo
      }
    }

  console.log(variacoes);
```

Tentei fazer uma cópia sem referencia dessas formas:

```
var variacoes = Object.assign({}, categoriaForm.variacoes);
```

Também tentei:

```
var variacoes = { ...categoriaForm.variacoes };
```

Porém dessas duas formas, quando eu printo a variável variação eu percebo que meu index continua lá. Coloquei aquele console.log e percebi que não está entrando dentro do meu for.

Tem algo a mais que precisa ser feito quando é copiado um objeto dessa forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara não o jeito mais bonito mas assim funciona:

```
var minhaVar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```